# When I restart my computer then sometimes it hang at BIOS

Tags: boot, reboot, desktop-computer

I have seen that when I restart my computer then sometimes (6/10) it hangs at screen where its says `Press f2 for setup at BIOS` Then processor starts making too much noise with fan

I have to gain power off and then do it again and then boots.

I see that red light of hard disc don't light when it hangs . But when it booths then that hard disk light show ok

I want to know where is the problem and what I can do about it

Comment: I think this issue could be relevant to anything. Personally, I'd think a possible faulty SATA port (assuming you're using SATA). Try an alternative port. The BIOS may be having troubles reading from the hard disk during boot. Although, I suspect this won't have anything to do with not letting the system complete POST. What troubleshooting methods have you applied?